# Zooming an Image by bilinear Interpolation method in java

Tags: java, image-processing, arrays, bufferedimage, bilinear-interpolation

I am trying to read an image, zoom it in to 80*60 and then zoom out the resulted image 5 times by bilinear Interpolation method. But I get this error : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4800 . Can anyone help me please?

this is what I have done :

```
import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Graphics2D;
    import java.awt.Image;
    import java.awt.RenderingHints;
    import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
    import java.awt.image.DataBufferByte;
    import java.awt.image.WritableRaster;
    import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;

    import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

    public class BiInterpolationTest {

        public static int zh;
        public static int zw;


        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            int[][] savedImage;

            File  f = new File ("F:\\Java\\Gray Scale Images\\3.jpg"); 
            savedImage = readimage(f);
            BufferedImage grayImage = new BufferedImage(savedImage.length, savedImage[0].length, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);

            for (int i =0 ; i<savedImage.length ; i ++){
            for (int j=0 ; j<savedImage[0].length ; j++){
                    int rgb = savedImage[i][j];
                    rgb = (rgb<<16)|(rgb<<8)|(rgb);
                    grayImage.setRGB(i, j, rgb);

                    BufferedImage zoomin =ScaledImage(grayImage, 80,60);
                     zh = zoomin.getHeight();
                     zw = zoomin.getWidth();


            byte[] tempArr;
                tempArr = extractBytes(zoomin);
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block

            byte [] zoomout;
            zoomout = bilineraInterpolation(tempArr , 5); 
            InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(zoomout);
            BufferedImage bImageInterpolated;
            try {
                bImageInterpolated = ImageIO.read(in);
                ImageIO.write(bImageInterpolated, "jpg", new File(
                        "F:/new-darksouls.jpg"));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            }

            }

        }

            public static BufferedImage ScaledImage(Image img, int w , int h){

            BufferedImage resizedImage = new BufferedImage(w , h , BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
            Graphics2D g2 = resizedImage.createGraphics();
            g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
            g2.drawImage(img, 0, 0, w, h, null);
            g2.dispose();
            return resizedImage;
            }
            /////////////////////////////////////
            public static byte[] extractBytes (BufferedImage Image) throws IOException {

                 BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(Image.getHeight(), Image.getWidth(), BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);

                 // get DataBufferBytes from Raster
                 WritableRaster raster = bufferedImage .getRaster();
                 DataBufferByte data   = (DataBufferByte) raster.getDataBuffer();

                 return ( data.getData() );
                }    


         public static int[][] readimage(File filename){
                BufferedImage img;

                try {
                    img = ImageIO.read(filename);

                    // Gray_scaled Image output

                    int width = img.getWidth();
                    int height = img.getHeight();
                    ImagePro.fw=width;
                    ImagePro.fh = height;
                    int [][] readimageVal = new int [width][height];
                    for (int i = 0; i<height ; i++){
                        for (int j =0  ; j<width ; j++){

                            Color c = new Color(img.getRGB(j, i));
                               int r= (int)(c.getRed() * 0.299)&0xff;
                               int g = (int)(c.getGreen() * 0.587)&0xff;
                               int b = (int)(c.getBlue() *0.114)&0xff;
                               int avg = ((r+b+g));

                            readimageVal[j][i] = avg;
                                }
                                }
                    return readimageVal;

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }


         public static byte[] bilineraInterpolation(byte[] ImgData, int ratio) {

           int wf = zw*ratio;
           int hf = zh*ratio;
           byte[] tempArr = new byte[wf*hf] ;
           int A, B, C, D, x, y, index, g ;
           float x_ratio = ((float)(zw))/wf ;
           float y_ratio = ((float)(zh))/hf ;
           float x_diff, y_diff ;
           int in = 0 ;
           for (int i=0;i<hf;i++) {
               for (int j=0;j<wf;j++) {
                   x = (int)(x_ratio * j) ;
                   y = (int)(y_ratio * i) ;
                   x_diff = (x_ratio * j) - x ;
                   y_diff = (y_ratio * i) - y ;
                   index = y*zw+x ;

                   // range is 0 to 255 thus bitwise AND with 0xff
                   A = ImgData[index] & 0xff ;
                   B = ImgData[index+1] & 0xff ;
                   C = ImgData[index+zw] & 0xff ;
                   D = ImgData[index+zw+1] & 0xff ;

                            g = (int)(
                           A*(1-x_diff)*(1-y_diff) +  B*(x_diff)*(1-y_diff) +
                           C*(y_diff)*(1-x_diff)   +  D*(x_diff*y_diff)
                           ) ;

                   tempArr[in++] = (byte) g ;                                   
               }
           }
           return tempArr ;
       }
         }
```

Comment: You asked this question like an hour ago, most of the world hasn't even had a chance to see it yet. Don't try and dump the question by re-posting, give it time for the audience to see it and formulate an answer, in the meantime, you could be honing your debugging skills, trying to see if you can find out what's wrong

Comment: @ MadProgrammer : I am so sorry, I posted it by mistake . I was trying to edit some tags on it but got duplicated .